# C++ Multiple Definition on Compilation

Tags: c++

I did an exercise in C++ which search for strings inside files and then stores what he found.
My problem is when I had the main() function inside the file "FilesSearcher.cpp" I got no problem during the compilation, after I moved the "main()" function to the file "test_file_searcher.cpp" I'm getting this error:

```
g++ test_file_searcher.cpp FileContent.cpp FilesSearcher.cpp
/tmp/ccc4qRPc.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): multiple definition of `SEARCH_MATRIX'
/tmp/cc8AjKPB.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccc4qRPc.o:(.data.rel.local+0x30): multiple definition of `EXTS_ARRAY'
/tmp/cc8AjKPB.o:(.data.rel.local+0x30): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My Files headers:

**FileContent.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class FileContent {
    public:
        FileContent(char *path, char *ext, char *content, int size);
        ~FileContent();
        char *get_path();
        char *get_ext();
        char *get_content();
        int get_size();

    private:
        char *mPath;
        char *mExt;
        char *mContent;
        int mSize;
};
```

**FilesSearcher.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "FileContent.h"

#define ENV_HOME    "HOME"
#define LINUX_BASE_DIR_PATH   "/"

#define IS_REGULAR_FILE 0x1
#define IS_DIRECTORY 0x2

#define PATH_THIS "."
#define PATH_PARENT ".."

#define SIZE_SEARCH_MATRIX 0x6
const char *SEARCH_MATRIX[] = {"test\0", "prova\0", "lol\0", "asd\0", "lmao\0", "rotfl\0"};

#define SIZE_EXTS_ARRAY 0x1
const char *EXTS_ARRAY[] = {"txt\0"};

const char * get_home_path();

const char * get_desktop_path();

void parse_files(const char *path, std::vector<FileContent*> &found_files);

void search_file_content(const char **search, const char *file_path, std::vector<FileContent*> &found_files);

int is_regular_file_or_dir(const char *path);

char *format_filepath(const char *base, const std::initializer_list<char *> &rel);

char *get_file_ext(const char *file_path);

char *get_last_relative_path(const char *file_path);

bool check_file_ext(const char **exts_arr, const char *file_path);

char *sub_array(const char* arr, int start, int end);

void print_dir_entry_info(dirent *entry, int num_entry);
```

**test_file_searcher.cpp**

```
#include "FilesSearcher.h"
int main(){
    using namespace std;

    std::vector<FileContent*> found_files;

    const char *home_path = get_desktop_path();
    cout << "[+] Home Path: " << home_path << endl;
    std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    parse_files(home_path, found_files);

    if(found_files.size() > 0x0){
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("example.txt");
        for(int i = 0x0; i < found_files.size(); i++){
            FileContent *fc = found_files[i];
            myfile << fc->get_path() << "\n" << fc->get_content() << "\n\n";
            delete fc;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    return 0x0;
}
```

Inside FileContent.cpp I have only as include:

```
#include "FileContent.h"
```

Inside FilesSearcher.cpp as includes I have:

```
#include "FilesSearcher.h"
```

Can you please tell me where is the error? I cannot found it :/
I already tryed changing the "includes" but nothing changed.

Thank you so much!
Have a nice coding :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const char *SEARCH_MATRIX[] = {"test\0", "prova\0", "lol\0", "asd\0", "lmao\0", "rotfl\0"};`

Is defined in a header file.  Each time you include this, in a different CPP file, you get that defined in that translation unit.

Put `inline` in front of these symbols.  That is a keyword whose modern meaning is to allow it to be in a header.

---

Meanwhile, there are a lot of bad practices in that code.  Once you get it working correctly, you might post on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack to get some pointers.  (Or just browse that to see what very common review issues apply to you as well.)

Comment: Thank you really fast! I was trying with extern but didn't worked!

Comment: What does "inline" do here? I mean it works like "inline to a function" so the compilator place the litteral value insteald of a reference?
Thank you

Comment: You would use `extern` in the header (without the initial value) _and_ one CPP file containing the actual definition.  That's what would have been necessary in older versions of C++, as `inline` variables were added in C++17.

Comment: `inline` means it can go in a header, and at link time only one (presumably identical) copy is taken.  That's understandable for variables as well as functions.  The original C meaning of `inline` was indeed a hint to the compiler to expand the code in-place rather than making a call.  But the "compilator" makes those decisions on its own now.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: A coda to the above: [The As If Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). TL;DR version: the compiler can do anything it wants to your program so long as you cannot observe the difference in observable behaviour. And this leads to another important point: Code is a description of program behaviour, not  list of instructions. The compiler interprets the behaviour described by the code and generate the list of instructions for you.